# IDE autocompletion broken with TypeScript mapped type + conditionals

Tags: typescript, types, autocomplete, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I've constructed a type that the IDE correctly infers on hover, but for some reason autocompletion of the object properties does not work.

The goal: I want a `createStyles` function that will take an object containing two types of styles.

1. Emotion CSS interpolations with the theme type predefined
2. Getters with explicitly defined props that return #1

I want them to be differentiated by each key's absence or presence of the `get` prefix.

Example:

```
const styles = createStyles({
  regular: (theme) => ({ color: theme.palette.red }),

  getFancy: (isDisabled: boolean) => (theme) => ({
    color: theme.palette[isDisabled ? 'gray' : 'red'
  }),
});
```

The initial type that I constructed resolves the final object perfectly fine, and type checking works throughout construction of the styles object passed in, but IDE autocompletion of each CSS object's properties does not work:

```
type GetterKey = `get${Capitalize<string>}`;

const createStyles = <
  TStyles extends {
    [K in keyof TStyles]: K extends GetterKey
      ? (...args: any[]) => Interpolation<Theme>
      : Interpolation<Theme>;
  }
>(
  styles: TStyles
) => styles;
```

I extended the index type and was able to get autocomplete working for the getters, but not the regular Interpolations:

```
const createStyles = <
  TStyles extends {
    [K in keyof TStyles extends GetterKey
      ? GetterKey
      : Exclude<keyof TStyles, GetterKey>]: K extends GetterKey
      ? (...args: any[]) => Interpolation<Theme>
      : Interpolation<Theme>;
  }
>(
  styles: TStyles
) => styles;
```

My initial thought was that I'm hitting a limit of TypeScript with regard to it deferring resolution of generics... but the end type and all type checking is spot on, so I'm confused how autocomplete could be broken. I verified the same behavior in VS Code and CodeSandbox.

Here is a simplified sandbox without Emotion:

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-autocomplete-0tnn1b?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Is your question primarily about getting it to work, or understanding why your version doesn't work? They are distinct questions and require different approaches to answer, and I'd like to know where to spend my effort.

Comment: Like, your version doesn't work because the TS inference algorithm can't do arbitrary contextual typing and generic type argument specification at the same time; they happen in phases or passes and sometimes these passes happen in an order where, for example, the generic type is inferred correctly but too late to do contextual typing.  If that's what you want to know, then I'd need to track down authoritative sources for that. ...

Comment: ...  On the other hand, if you just want something that works (without refactoring to break the input object into multiple pieces) then I'd look into something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR0PEm) which tries to give a specific constraint... an ugly and imperfect constraint, but a specific one, to help the inference.  If I write that up I'd need to spend a lot of time explaining it.  So which way should I try to go here?

Comment: Hi @jcalz; I'm so sorry for the late reply. Your answer was, as always, incredible. I ended up using your "ugly and imperfect" constraint and it worked perfectly.

I feel like this is somewhat of a common theme that I run into - essentially we're filtering for things that are NOT vs things that are, which TS doesn't have easy mechanisms for.